# Interarrival times using timeseries data

Tags: time-series, modeling, interarrival-time

I am attempting to model user requests coming into a computer system. Is there a good way to generate interarrival times for requests using timeseries data?

Specifically, my data in the form of requests/minute, and I want to generate the interarrival times (or the arrival times) between each request, adhering to the data.

My data looks like the following:

| Minute | Number of Requests |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 4 | 12 |

and so on...

What I would want to generate is something like

| Request ID | Arrival Time (seconds) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 16 |

Originally I assumed that within each minute, requests follow a Poisson distribution with rate=1/(number of requests) to generate exponentially distributed interarrival times. However, that is not really a good assumption because there is no "smoothing" of request rate between intervals. E.g., for the first two data points in first above table, one would expect the request rate to be higher towards the end of the first minute. Assuming Poisson distribution within the entire minute does not capture this because with this requirement it is no longer "memoryless".

How can I do better?

Edit: I also know that these requests are meant to be bursty in practice, and maybe using a log normal distribution would make more sense?

Comment: Idea: Use two Possion generators, one for current/previous interval and one for next. Weight their emissions by how far into the window you are, and sum the events together.

Comment: Interesting idea... Lets assume that I weigh events as 1 if they're in the same interval, and linearly decrease the weight to 0 in the next interval (even though I'm not sure if the linear decrease is reasonable). But what does it mean to _sum_ weighted events? Either the request happens or not. Taking a union would unnecessarily increase the number of events. Are you suggesting these events are summed as some sort of probabilities?

Comment: I was thinking that the 'acceptance' of the events from each generator would also have a probability based on the weight

Comment: Also check the paper I-SMOOTH: Iteratively smoothing piecewise-constant Poisson-process rate functions

Comment: Thanks, those make sense. One other idea I was trying out is to use KDE on the number-of-requests histogram and then use the resulting function as the time-varying lambda as the Poisson parameter. Poisson doesn't necessarily give me a bursty behaviour though, so I'll look into translating this into log-normal or some other heavy tailed distribution.